# Chrome Web App Manifest Keep Query Params

Tags: angular, google-chrome, manifest, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I have tried several things and done a lot of research, but haven't found something for my problem.

Description:

I have a Web App manifest.json from an Angular-App:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "start_url": "index.html",
  "display": "standalone"
}
```

Now i have written a new Angular app and tried to keey the query params, because they are necessary to set some station like setting eg. to set a workstation name like

```
http://myapp.app-server.my/?workstation=PC-MYSTATION
```

This is necessary to predefine station like settings, but when i now save a shortcut with the chrome tools the query params are gone.

Is there a way to keep them with manifest.json or is there a better way to achieve this?

I don't want to setup manual chrome execution params like this way for many desktop shortcuts:

```
"...Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=http://myapp.app-server.my/?workstation=PC-MYSTATION
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry forgot the links to the Web App Manifests which i'am talking about:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Manifest

**EDIT2 (actual workaround):**

Actually when i remove the start_url entry the manifest would be invalid, but saving the shortcut works with query GET Parameters on a Windows Device.

Comment: Have you tried making `manifest.json` generate dynamic data? When on `https://example.com/?workstation=PC-MYSTATION` you would have `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json?workstation=PC-MYSTATION">` which would return with a custom `"start_url": "./?workstation=PC-MYSTATION"`

Comment: When you tell me how i can do this via GET parameter i can try. But actually i have no idea how to make this work.